# How to save state of layout in fragment android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout, tabs

I am working with tab layout with view pager and have ran into a problem, and I am not sure how to solve this, I have searched online but haven't found anything useful to work with.

I wasn't able to take video, so instead took screenshots:

[image]
Scenario of these screen shots:

```
I am on tab 1,
I enter in a name and press enter button
layout 1 visiblity is view.Gone and layout 2 is view.visible
I swipe/click to tab 2
I swipe/click to tab 3
when I swipe/click to tab 1
I expect layout visiblity to be view.visible and layout 1 to be view.gone
instead the app does not save the state at which I left
and goes back showing layout 1
```

**The problem:**
I have 3 tabs, currently tab 2 and 3 are empty and I am working on tab 1. For tab 1, I have put two layouts and am using visibility function to show/hide tabs based on if-else statement. First layout contains a edittext field with a button and for time being the second layout of tab 1 is empty. The if-else statement checks if the user has written in their name in layout 1 and if so, it will make visibility of layout 1 View.GONE and make tab 2 View.VISIBLE.

However, when the user has written in a correct name and the app has validated it, it goes to layout 2 but when user goes to either by swipe or by click tab 2 or 3 and then go back to tab 1, layout 1 comes to top again and layout 2 is gone.

What I want to do is, if the app has validated and is showning layout 2 in tab 1, then I want the app to save this state and if the user changes tabs and come back to tab 1, I want the layout 2 to be shown and not 1.

My layout for tab 1 is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/entered"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Welcome"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:hint="Your Name"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/enter"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:text="Enter" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The if statement I have written to validate user input, currently it will only proceed to layout 2, if the text is 'name':

```
if (name.getText().toString().equals("name")){
                layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
```

Sorry about the lengthy post, I wasn't sure best way of explaining my problem. In case my post isn't clear, what I want to do is save the state of fragment layouts in tab 1 so when user changes tabs e.g. to tab 2 or 3 and comes back to tab 1, I want the layout that was shown when they left tab 1 to be shown.

If my question/post is not clear please let me know and thanks in advance, I hope I have explained myself properly.

EDITED:

Global variable:

```
public MenuItem  settings;

  if (name.getText().toString().equals("name")){
                    layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    settings.setEnabled(true);
                }else {
                    layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     settings.setEnabled(false);

                }
```

**EDITED 2**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    public boolean shouldShowItem = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        if (name.getText().toString().equals("name")){
            layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            shouldShowItem = true;
        }else {
            layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            shouldShowItem = false;

        }


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
        if (shouldShowItem)
            menu.getItem(item_index).setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It will depend upon adapter you are using for ViewPager you should use FragmentStatePagerAdapter which save state of object.OnPause and OnResume method is called for FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: the adapter I am using only has getitem and getcount

Comment: Please can  you direct me / give me an example of adapter implementing onpause and onresume

Comment: you can watch a tutorial in youtube by  Android Fragments Tutorial
by slidenerd and go through 27-30 you will definately get answere.If you need example let me know

Comment: example would be great, however, I am watching these tuts, there are really useful

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int offset)
```

In your case, you want to specify 2, so that when you are on the third page, the first one is not destroyed, and vice-versa.

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Regarding the menu:

Take a look at the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
```

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is
>   called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can
>   use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise
>   dynamically modify the contents.

So you should handle that from the Activity.

```
@Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
     if (shouldShowItem)
         menu.getItem(item_index).setEnabled(false);
     return true;
 }
```

On changes, you need to call

```
invalidateOptionsMenu()
```

and the the menu will be redraw

Comment: do I define this in mainactivity, view pager class or in my fragment 1 class or will this work I cliked to another tab rather then swiping.

Comment: Depends where you created it, in your Main Activity I assume

Comment: Thanks, I will try it now and let you know

Comment: Hi, this worked like a charm however, I thought it would solve it but it didn't please have a look at my edit. In my if-else statment I am enabling disabling a menuitem called setting based on which layout is shown, however, when user switches from tab 2 or 3 to tab 1 the setting icon is always disabled.

Comment: i need more code, where are you trying to disable the setting button?

Comment: inside the if else statement

Comment: please see edited, I thought my edited came through but it didn't let me know if you require more details

Comment: its in my fragment 1 (tab 1 activity)

Comment: please mark it as the right answer if i've helped you

Comment: Hi, sorry i didn;t get a chance to try this out. I am try it now, btw do I need to define the shouldShowItem before hands?

Comment: and by On changes, you need to call, do you mean the if statement?

Comment: What do you mean 'before hands'?

Comment: do I need to define, shouldShowItem as global variable before using it in onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: It should be a member in the Activity

Comment: Hi, please see edited 2, if I try in this format my app crashes

Answer (score 1):

give Memory to Your ViewPager:
1.

```
MyAdapter mAdapter= new MyAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
  mAdapter.contents.add(new Fragment1());
  mAdapter.contents.add(new Fragment2());
  mAdapter.contents.add(new Fragment3());
  mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

2. This is adapter for your pager

> ```
> class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
>         String[] pageTitle = {"Dummy 1", "Dummy 2", "Dummy 3"};
>
>         public JantriPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
>             super(fm);
>         }
>
>         ArrayList<Fragment> contents = new ArrayList<>();
>
>         @Override
>         public Fragment getItem(int position) {
>             return contents.get(position);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public int getCount() {
>             return 3;
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
>             return pageTitle[position];
>         }
>     }
> ```

3. Now create three fragment name

   class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

   }
   .
   .
4. Now your state is automatically saved

Comment: setting an offset pages should be used.

Comment: That's Ok,what about if each fragment contains images there is posibility of OEM and if you have to create more than 3 fragment.